# How to handle req parameters in Middleware function

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I want to handle request parameter in middleware function in expressjs framework. To describe my problem I created very small working example. Let's consider I want to have a language parameter in the path and change its value to default if the given value is wrong (not supported language). Let's assume I only support *'en'* and *'fi'* languages and I want to set the *"lang"* parameter to *'fi'* if user given anything else than *['en', 'fi']*.

To do that I prepared a below piece of code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// MIDDLEWARE FUNTION
function handleLang(req, res, next) {
    console.log("from handleLang I see params: "); console.log(req.params)
    var supportedLangs = ['en', 'fi']
    if (req.params.lang === undefined || (supportedLangs.indexOf(req.params.lang) == -1)) {
        console.log("so changing req.params.lang to default...")
        req.params.lang = "fi"
        console.log("before I leave handleLang I see req.params as: "); console.log(req.params)
    }
    return next()
}

app.use("/:lang*?", handleLang)

app.get('/:lang*?', function (req, res) {
    console.log('from app.get I see following params: '); console.log(req.params)
    res.send('index')
})

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server started....')
})
```

I expected that the the handleLang function will change the lang to default value and I will see that in get function. Unfortunately I was wrong.

When I go to address http://localhost:4000/xx, I see following output:

```
Server started....
from handleLang I see params:
{ '0': '', lang: 'xx' }
so changing req.params.lang to default...
before I leave handleLang I see req.params as:
{ '0': '', lang: 'fi' }
from app.get I see following params:
{ '0': '', lang: 'xx' }
from handleLang I see params:
{ '0': '', lang: 'favicon.ico' }
so changing req.params.lang to default...
before I leave handleLang I see req.params as:
{ '0': '', lang: 'fi' }
from app.get I see following params:
{ '0': '', lang: 'favicon.ico' }
```

I have no idea why req.params.lang somehow changes to *'favicon.ico'* and I don't understand why I see the same message twice. Can anyone explain me why it happens and describe how it should be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach can be that you can set the language inside middleware like below:

```
`req.headers['language'] = 'fi';`
```

You can later access this value like below:

`console.log(req.headers['language'])`

Comment: thanks, that works, but do you have any idea if I can put it somehow into req.params?

Comment: We can also use a way descried inside the issue: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2911

Comment: @nosbor anyway, please notice, that this would definitely overwrite the language header if it gets passed by the client. it would be a small percentage, but this would definitely overwrite the header if it would be used for something else than the current purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the browser you might be using.

Many browsers (Chrome and Firefox, for example) do automatically try to get the `favicon.ico` file if not specified. This is the file, where the icon for your website is saved.

Most sites on the web use this filename and location (in root directory), which leads most browser to get the file automatically from there, if not explicit specified. I personally think, that this is a undefined standard most people use.

What actually happens is this:

1. You enter `http://localhost:4000/xx` to the browsers address bar, which leads to the request you actually wanted.
2. Your browser wants to display the icon of the site you are visiting and it checks the cache for it. Because you do not have a website icon, the browser tries to get the icon within a new request. Because again you did not explicit set the location for the website icon, the browser automatically tries to get it from `http://localhost:4000/favion.ico`, which gets parsed by express as your `lang` parameter.

As a result you see your actual request `http://localhost:4000/xx` and the automatically request `http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico` issued by your browser. This is why the language param is set to `favicon.ico` for the last request.

Comment: thank you for explanation, any idea if there is any good solution for above problem (replacing the value of variable in req.params)?

Comment: @nosbor to be honest, I do not know the answer for your second question. I knew the part with the two requests (and favicon), so technically I answered your inital question.